# Rails 3 : (Devise + Omniauthable) Facebook app_request return query string parameter how I can grab it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

How I can grab the query url parameters coming from a callback from Facebook?

I am using devise + omniauthable, and everything works perfectly. I just don't have any  idea how to access those parameters. I know that omniauth stores them automatically, and that I can acquire them using `request.env['omniauth.origin']`, but where do I do this request?

I have a service controller (`class Users::ServicesController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`) that does all the authentication process using omniauthable methods (this is made for multiple different providers), and everything works fine when I use the signup method with the root users/callback/Facebook, I can grab all the parameters that the `omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']` provides, and save it in the database or update the users info.

If I want to also access the query url parameters, coming from a direct callback from Facebook (the user accepts the Facebook app_request from Facebook platform), in this case Facebook appends to users/callback/Facebook? request_ids=xv552180 72

How can I grab these request_ids coming from the url? I'd like to use it to verify which request was accepted (hypothetical an user can have multiple requests from other users, but when he/she accept, it's only one that is accepted every time). I want then to be able to grab the requests_id, and pass it to a method, that will update friendships for the current accepting user, and the user who sent that request, and that was accepted only.

I need to save it in the database in my services controller or I can access it also on the fly just after that the user was redirect to my app?

On the omniauth page, there is nothing about it.